# VirtualHost in Apache 2.4 replaces DocumentRoot when using http://localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm using Yosemite with Apache 2.4

*/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Everything is fine, `http://localhost` directs me to the default */Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html*

After adding `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to */private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*

And adding the config below to */private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@xxx.com
    ServerName xxx.local
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx"
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx/">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When using `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` from the browser, Apache directs me to */Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx/index.html* instead of */Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html*, how can I fix it?, please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "fix it"? This is completely expected behaviour... Why not just change the `DocumentRoot` to `/Library/WebServer/Documents` if that's what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed out `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/"` it's already there in the file *httpd.conf*, but I still have this problem

Comment: But now your `DocumentRoot` is `/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx` instead of `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` so obviously the problem remains.

Comment: @arco444 that's right, actually `DocumentRoot` has been there but I just forgot to mention in the post, `http://localhost` directs to the path specified in `VirtualHost`'s `DocumentRoot`

Comment: Why don't you just remove the included `httpd-vhosts.conf` file if that's not where you want the `DocumentRoot` to be? Once you define a VirtualHost it will take precedence over default settings.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem today.

### I found solution here: [httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

**Main host goes away**

Any request that doesn't match an existing  is handled by the global server configuration, regardless of the hostname or ServerName.

When you add a name-based virtual host to an existing server, and the virtual host arguments match preexisting IP and port combinations, requests will now be handled by an explicit virtual host. In this case, it's usually wise to create a default virtual host with a ServerName matching that of the base server. New domains on the same interface and port, but requiring separate configurations, can then be added as subsequent (non-default) virtual hosts.

Comment: I meant, my requirement is I like to maintain both `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` to access the global `DocumentRoot` which is `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` and `http://xxx.local` to access `/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxx/`
Is this similar to what problem you used to face, and already solved it?